# react-native-fbsdk-next,The old application is able to use deprecated fields

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook-graph-api

Unfortunately，I'm a beginner and this is my first time trying out this component library.

It seems that the fields imageUrl, contentTitle, and contentDescription in ShareLinkContent should have been deprecated in API 2.9 based on the comments.
/**

- The URL of a picture to attach to this comment.
- @deprecated imageUrl is deprecated from Graph API 2.9.
- For more information, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_deprecations.
  */

However, there is an application that configured these three fields three years ago, and it can display images and titles correctly when sharing website links in the feed.

This application's API version, which I found on developers.facebook.com, is v17.0.

The code below is for the old application：

```
  const getShareContent = ({
    type,
    shareWaysType,
    wechantShareContent,
    facebookShareContent,
    sharePreviewItem,
  }: GetShareContentProps) => {
    const { title, description, banner } = sharePreviewItem
    if (!title || !description || !banner) return null

    switch (shareWaysType) {
      case IShareWaysType.Wechat:
        const cloneWechatContent = clone(wechantShareContent)
        cloneWechatContent.title =
          wechantShareContent.scene === WXScene.WXSceneSession
            ? title
            : getWXSceneTimelineTitle(title, type)
        cloneWechatContent.description =
          wechantShareContent.scene === WXScene.WXSceneSession
            ? description
            : getWXSceneTimelineDescription(description, type)
        cloneWechatContent.thumbImageUrl = sharePreviewBanner || banner

        return cloneWechatContent
      case IShareWaysType.Facebook:
        const cloneFackbookContent = clone(facebookShareContent)
        cloneFackbookContent.contentTitle = title
        cloneFackbookContent.contentDescription = description
        cloneFackbookContent.imageUrl = sharePreviewBanner || banner
        return cloneFackbookContent
      default:
        return null
    }
  }
    const facebookContent = getShareContent({
      type,
      shareWaysType: IShareWaysType.Facebook,
      facebookShareContent: { ...fackbookShareContent, contentUrl },
      sharePreviewItem,
    }) as IShareLinkContent

    if (!facebookContent) {
      global?.toast?.open(translate("Community.ParameterError"))
      close?.()
      return
    }

    ShareDialog.canShow(facebookContent)
      .then((canShow: boolean) => {
        if (canShow) {
          ShareDialog.setMode("native")
          return ShareDialog.show(facebookContent)
            .then(() => {
              close?.()
              onSuccess?.()
            })
            .catch(() => {
              ShareDialog.setMode("automatic")
              if (type === IShareType.NotCampaignShareNEarn) {
                close?.()
              }
              return ShareDialog.show(facebookContent).catch(error => {
                global.toast?.open(`${translate("Community.SharingFailed")}：${error}`)
              })
            })
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        onPress?.()
      })
  })
```

I would like to know what could be the possible reason for this situation.

Also, I wanted to ask if there are any alternative fields or methods for these deprecated fields? Or does this mean that we won't be able to attach images and titles when sharing website links in the future?

Thank you sincerely for any responses and suggestions.

I have been trying to use these three fields in an application recently, but without success.

Comment: Domain verification still allows to specify these fields while posting a link. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are you suggesting that domain validation needs to be performed before using these fields, or can I directly use these three fields like I did in the code I previously shared?

Comment: Yes, you will need domain validation for this to work - otherwise, Facebook will simply ignore any attempts to dynamically set title, description & thumbnail, and will use the values fetched from the OG meta tags (or if those are missing, the page content) of the shared URL instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll give domain validation a try.

Comment: I apologize for my previous mistake in expressing myself. My requirement is to share a link on Facebook using my registered application. In this case, it seems that those three fields cannot be used anymore. The old application used to share a server-rendered page, allowing Facebook to automatically fetch the title and image. After modifying the link, it is now successfully displayed. Thank you again for CBore's response.